# Highlight Grid View Row based on second SQL query results

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview

I am working with ASP.NET and VB.NET in code behind. My question is this:

I have a grid view (Called gvSecondLevel) that is loaded based on query A. (It works fine) The grid view can have anywhere from 1 to X number of rows. There is a Command Button for every row in column zero of gvSecondLevel that when clicked will display another grid view (Called gvThirdLevel) which will display 1 to X number of rows for the line number in gvSecondLevel.

In the gvThirdLEvel there is column called OpComplete, it is either 0 (No) or 255 (Yes). So lets say that gvSecondLevel has 2 lines. For Line 1 there are three lines in the gvThirdLevel, and for gvSecondLevel line 2 there are 4 lines in gvThirdLevel.

Now assume that for gvSecondLevel Line 1 that all OpComplete steps (In gvThirdLEvel) are 255 or Complete.

But for gvSecondLevel Line 2 lets say that the third line (of the four lines) of gvThirdLevel has an OpComplete step that is a 0 but lines 1,2, & 4 are all complete or 255.

What I need to do is have line 2 in gvSecondLevel highlighted because of the third line in gvThirdLevel OpComplete being 0. The kicker is that the gvThirdLevel is not visible UNTIL the user has clicked a line number in gvSecondLevel.

So in essence I need to some how look at all the lines that would be retrieved by the gvThidLevel query for each line in gvSecondlevel and highlight it so that a user knows that a particular line has a problem.

Right now the gvSecondLevel loads but no lines are highlighted. Can anyone point in a direction so that I can try and learn how to do this? Or if by some miracle someone has already had to do this and can share some code that also would work so I can see how it is done.

### Update

gvSecondLvl

```
____________________________________________________________________________
|           |Line # | Part Description | PCS | Weight | Sq Foot | Comments |
____________________________________________________________________________
|[cmdButton]|   1   | Part blah blah   | 100 | 1,200  | 254     |          |
____________________________________________________________________________
|[cmdButton]|   2   | Part blah blah 2 | 50  | 1,500  | 125     |          |
____________________________________________________________________________
```

This loads fine. When someone clicks the cmdButton for a specific line number the gvThirdLvl is Displayed, lets say line 2

gvThirdLvl

```
___________________________________________________________________________
| Step Comp | Assembly | OP # | WC Code | Due Date  | Qty | Qty Completed |
___________________________________________________________________________
|   Yes     |    0     | 100  | MTLH    | 6/12/2017 | 25  |     25        |
___________________________________________________________________________
|    No     |    0     | 110  |  PC     | 6/14/2017 | 100 |      0        |
___________________________________________________________________________
```

Remember that the gvThirdLvlv will not be displayed until the line 2 command button in gvSecondLvl is clicked. But when gvSecondLvl loads I need (in this case) line 2 to be highlighted before any line numbers is clicked. That way the users can see that line 2 (in this case) is the reason that this order is on the report.

Comment: TLDR, I skimmed to the summary where you basically said you haven't even tried anything yet. Your requirements are buried somewhere in that wall of text but the description just goes on and on. We need some details about what you are trying to accomplish that explain the situation clearly.

Comment: Highlight row in gridview1 based on cell in gridview 2 that doesnt display unless you click a command button for a line in gridview1

Comment: I'm sure this description means something to you but it is not at all clear to me. You might want to check out this link to improve this question before it gets closed for being unclear. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That is part of the problem. I am not sure the best way to explain it. It is very hard to explain simply because of what is needed. I guess if it gets closed it gets closed but I have seen other questions on here that were longer and much more involved that didn't have any clear answer and not be closed.

Comment: Maybe if you can mock up an image of what you are trying to do it would help. The text description of this is just way too much to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are populating the rows when you click the button you can set the row background color on the data bind event.  Then if the row that is being bound matches your criteria you can highlight it.

```
Private Sub GridView_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView.RowDataBound, additionalGridView.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If CType(e.Row.FindControl("Line_1"), TextBox).Text = "0" Then
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally managed to get it work.

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To gvDetailSecondLevel.Rows.Count - 1
        'If gvDetailSecondLevel.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text.ToString > "0" Then
        Dim jNumber As String = lblSONum.Text
        Dim lNumber As String = gvDetailSecondLevel.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text.ToString
        Dim soNumber As String = jNumber & "." & lNumber
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(myConnection2)
            conn.Open()
            Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
                sqlCmd.CommandText = ("Select jo.OpComplete From JobOper jo Where jo.JobNum = @JobNum")
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobNum", soNumber)
                sqlCmd.Connection = conn
                Using sqlDa As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
                    Using sqlDT As New DataTable()
                        sqlDa.Fill(sqlDT)
                        For Each row As DataRow In sqlDT.Rows
                            If row.Item(0) = "0" Then
                                gvDetailSecondLevel.Rows(i).BackColor = Color.Yellow
                                gvDetailSecondLevel.Rows(i).ForeColor = Color.Red
                            End If
                        Next
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
            conn.Close()
         End Using
         Next
```

This code is in the gvSecondLvlv DataBound.